# ¿Porqué no puedo ordenar las columnas de mi datatables del lado del servidor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, datatable

Tengo un problema en mi datatables del lado del servidor.

No puedo ordenar las columnas ya sea de forma ascedente o descendente; agregé las directivas de configuración como el `ordering`, `aaSorting`, `order`, etc. pero no logró el ordenamiento de las columnas de mi listado.

En la consulta a mi base de datos, incluyo un `ORDER BY` en mi sentencia pero solo para mostrar el listado de mis registros ordenados una vez que entre el usuario a consultar datos.

Anexo mi código para ver que puede hacerme falta o si es necesario enviar datos a la base de datos para que el datatables haga el ordenamiento que se requiere de las columnas.

```
          $(document).ready(function () {
                var status = '<?= $status ?>';
                var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                    "paging": true,
                    "info": true,
                    "filter": true,
                    "stateSave": true,
                    "ordering": true,

                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": baseurl+"cl_clientes/cl_listado2/"+status,
                        "type": "POST",
                        "dataSrc": "data",
                    },
                    "oLanguage": {
                            "sSearch": "Filtrar:",
                            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 a 0 de 0 registros.",
                            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron coincidencias.",
                            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrando de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                            "sLengthMenu": 'Mostrar <select>'+
                                '<option value="25">25</option>'+
                                '<option value="50">50</option>'+
                                '<option value="75">75</option>'+
                                '<option value="100">100</option>'+
                                '<option value="-1">Todos</option>'+
                                '</select> registros',
                            "oPaginate": {
                                "sFirst": "Primero",
                                "sLast": "Ultimo",
                                "sNext": ">>",
                                "sPrevious": "<<"
                              },
                            "sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                            "oAria": {
                                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                            }
                    },
                    "order": [
                            [ 1, "asc" ],
                            [ 2, "asc" ], 
                            [ 3, "asc" ], 
                            [ 4, "asc" ],
                            [ 5, "asc" ],
                            [ 6, "asc" ],
                            [ 7, "asc" ],
                            [ 8, "asc" ],
                            [ 9, "asc" ],
                            [ 10, "asc" ],
                            [ 11, "asc" ]
                    ],
                    "columns": [
                        {"data": 'cl_id_cliente'},      // 0
                        {"data": 'cl_id_cliente'},      // 1 
                        {"data": 'cl_clave_cliente'},   // 2
                        {"data": 'cl_nombre'},          // 3
                        {"data": 'cl_nombre_empresa'},  // 4
                        {"data": 'us_abreviatura'},     // 5
                        {"data": 'rt_nombre'},          // 6
                        {"data": 'cl_monto_debe'},      // 7
                        {"data": 'cl_correo'} ,         // 8
                        {"data": 'ds_nombre'},          // 9
                        {"data": 'cl_celular'},         // 10
                        {"data": 'cl_status_pedido'},   // 11
                        {"data": 'cl_id_cliente'},      // 12
                    ],
                    "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex){
                        if(data['cl_status'] == 0) {
                            $(row).addClass("danger");
                        }
                    },
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                        { 
                            "bSortable": false,
                            "targets": [0],
                            "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                               if(type === 'display'){
                                  data = '<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check_'+row.cl_id_cliente+'" clave="'+row.cl_id_cliente+'" class="tableflat check_'+row.cl_id_cliente+'" />';
                               }
                               return data;
                            },
                            "checkboxes": {
                               "selectRow": true,
                               "selectAllRender": '<input style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="check_principal dt-checkboxes" onClick="ChequearAlgunos2('+this+','+2+');"   name="2" type="checkbox" value="2" id="2"/>'
                            }
                        },
                        { 
                            "targets": [3],
                            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                return '<div data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="">'+
                                        row.cl_nombre+' '+row.cl_apellido_paterno+' '+row.cl_apellido_materno
                                        '</div>';
                            }
                        },
                        { 
                            "targets": [5],
                            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                return '<div data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="">'+
                                        row.us_abreviatura
                                        //row.us_nombre+' '+row.us_apellido_paterno+' '+row.us_apellido_materno
                                        '</div>';
                            }
                        },
                         { 
                            "targets": [7],
                            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                var monto = 0;

                                if(row.cl_monto_debe == 0){
                                    monto_debe = '$'+parseFloat(monto).toFixed(2);
                                } else {
                                    monto_debe = '$'+parseFloat(row.cl_monto_debe).toFixed(2);
                                }
                                return monto_debe;
                            }
                        },
                         { 
                            "bSortable": false,
                            "targets": [12],
                            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                /* Ligas para editar, activar o desactivar un cliente */
                                if(row.cl_status == 1){
                                    buttons = '<a href="'+baseurl+'cl_clientes/editar/'+row.cl_id_cliente+'">'+
                                        '<button type="button" class="btn color-primario btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>'+
                                        '</a>'+
                                        '<button onClick="statusClientee('+row.cl_id_cliente+', '+0+')" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" clave="'+row.cl_id_cliente+'">'+
                                        '<i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>';                                     
                                } 
                                if(row.cl_status == 0){
                                    buttons = '<a href="'+baseurl+'cl_clientes/editar/'+row.cl_id_cliente+'">'+
                                        '<button type="button" class="btn color-primario btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>'+
                                        '</a>'+
                                        '<button onClick="statusClientee('+row.cl_id_cliente+', '+1+')" type="button" class="btn color-secundario btn-sm" clave="'+row.cl_id_cliente+'">'+
                                        '<i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>';
                                }
                                return buttons;
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                    "iDisplayLength": 25,
                }); 

            });
```

Agradezco de su atenta respuesta a mi duda sobre el ordenamiento de columnas en mi datatable del lado del servidor.

Comment: Te falta `[ 0 , asc ],` en tu `order`

Comment: Disculpa, agregé el `[ 0, "asc" ]`, pero sigue sin cumplir con la función del ordenamiento; además, cabe aclarar que en esta columna no se requiere ordenar.

Gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Porque tienes los mismos datos en la columna 0 y columna 1?

Comment: @lupita El problema puede estar en la forma que los estas ordenando en el datatables, quiza esten ordenados en elservidor pero tu datatables lo ordena de otra forma, quita el order o deja solo ordenamiento por una sola columna o varias pero no todas

Comment: @alanfcm ocupo el dato en ambas columnas.

Comment: @alanfcm voy a probar, pero con o sin la directiva de `order` no me hace el respectivo ordenamiento; desde mi consulta tengo un `ORDER BY` que los trae ordenados por el id del registro en forma descendente.

Comment: Y si remueves el `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Mi listado de registros se muestra pero no en el orden en que se fueron creando cada uno de éstos, ya no se que más pueda estar fallando que no me permite el ordenamiento de mis columnas; ya intenté de diversas formas, porque toda la funcionalidad de mi datatables ya esta como se requería, el ordenamiento es el único que me esta fallando.

Comment: Que base de datos estas usando?

Comment: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

Comment: Postgresql, de hecho cuando tenía mi datatables del lado del cliente todo funcionaba correctamente en el ordenamiento de columnas.
Pero debido al aumento de la cantidad de registros, se vio la necesidad de hacer todo el procesamiento del lado del servidor; la mayoría de las funciones ya se han logrado, excepto este aspecto dentro del datatables.

Comment: @alanfcm gracias por el enlace, lo voy a checar.

Answer (score -1):

Yo uso esta sentencia para ordenar.

```
order: [[0, 'asc']],
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución considera revisar [answer], explica como solucionaría esto lo que se comenta en la pregunta.